# powershell or python for build automation

Tags: c#, .net, python, deployment, continuous-integration

We are currently using [Psake](https://github.com/psake/psake) for build automation and [Pstrami](http://pstrami.codeplex.com/) for deployment. Both are Powershell libraries. Other tools we use are 7zip to zip/unzip packages and [Tarantino](https://bitbucket.org/headspringlabs/tarantino/wiki/Home) for database change management. We mostly use this to build and deploy MVC .NET applications for windows.

Build process is pretty simple:

1. Compile and Build the solution using MsBuild
2. Run NUnit tests
3. Package into zip

Deployment script is pretty simple as well:

1. Create few folders
2. Add new IIS Application
3. Create DB
4. etc.

It is all working very well. The only issue I have is Powershell; I really dislike this language. It is very painful for me to work with.

I'm reading about Python and it seems very interesting.

My questions are:

1. Can Python compete with Powershel?
2. What are the Pros and Cons of Python and Powershell and who wins?
3. I'm also curious if anyone is using Python to build and deploy
   .NET applications and if you ran into any issues and thought of using anything else because of  that.

Note: I have seen few similar question on SO, but could not find anything closely related to CI and Build automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is a very good general purpose programming language. Powershell is a Microsoft's task automation framework. Powershell is therefore more of a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_specific_language). When it comes to scripting windows deployment, powershell is much more powerful than python. Also check out new features coming up in [Powershell V3](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/01/powershell-3/)